# Writing code expression in Calculate Value to find cell value or Minimum cell value?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, expression, syntax

I have a calculate value tool that I'm using to skip rasters without features/no data. I'm very new to python and do not know much about proper formatting and syntax. Right now, the tool works but gives false negatives(0 when the value is actually 1). I need those rasters that have **no data to be skipped**, not those whose values are 0 or larger. Here is what I have right now:

[image]

I think a better option may be to find the minimum or maximum cell value in each raster and use that to find the No Data rasters. However, I do not know how to write the code that would allow me to that.

Comment: Please always include the Python code from the code block as text so that it can be available to future searches.  For field calculator questions the picture is helpful too, but as it stands someone searching for "GetCellValue" would not find this question.

Comment: I note that you have not yet taken the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You seem to have asked four questions about basically the same narrow topic.  I'm hoping to find time to review them to offer advice on to structure them better but for now I think you should consider clicking the Accept check mark next to those answers that have helped you the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logical condition, `if 'No Data'` will always be true. I also believe the result would be 'NoData' not 'No Data' (no spaces).

Need to compare `n`; something like this:

```
if n == 'NoData':
    return False
else:
    return True
```